# SQL- Twitter First Five who tweeted

Tags: qsqlquery

Problem Statement
Write a Sql query to retrieve the usernames of the users who have tweeted on Twitter, ordered by the earliest tweet creation time, and limited to the first five users?

Tables Schema as Below:

users
columnName  dataType
id  int
username    varchar
email   varchar
remember_token  varchar
created_at  datetime
updated_at  datetime
password_digest varchar

tweets
columnName  dataType
id  int
content varchar
created_at  datetime
updated_at  datetime

UserTweetRelation
columnName  dataType
id  int
created_at  datetime
retweet boolean
user_id varchar
tweet_id    varchar
relationships
columnName  dataType
id  int
created_at  datetime
updated_at  datetime
follower_id int
followed_id int
Input
User Input is not applicable to this question.
Output
Run the code to print the output
Example
NA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.